# Finding the limit of a sequence in python, jupyter notebook

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, sequence, limit

I’ve got a sequence a(n)=(5-77sin(n)+8n^2)/(1-4n^2) and I’m trying to find a candidate for the limit of this sequence. How do I do this? I’ve tried using a code below but that didn’t work so any ideas?[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zUd3V.jpg)

Comment: Don't post an image of your code, but post your code in the message with balise. And be more specific on what went wrong with your code

Comment: Sorry I’m very new to python. After that code it has come up saying TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for ^: ‘Add’ and ‘int’. What does this mean?

Comment: You can make code blocks by putting three back ticks on a line followed by your code and then close it with another line of three back ticks. A back tick is the character ` . That is how I posted code that you could then use in my answer. An image isn't directly useable.

Comment: use ** for like n**2 not n^2

Comment: Please do not share information as images unless absolutely necessary. See: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors.

Comment: We need a [mcve], as well as the entire error message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As discussed [here](https://docs.sympy.org/latest/gotchas.html#mathematical-operators), for sympy you need to use `**` for raising to a power and not `^`.

This will work:

```py
from sympy import limit, sin, Symbol, oo
from sympy.abc import x ,n
r = limit((5-77*sin(n)+8*n**2)/(1-4*n**2),n , oo)
r
```

Adaptation of OP code based on:

- https://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/abc.html
- https://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/series/series.html